# Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index" after loop runs a few times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

```
def animate(i):
    global firstTime
    global btc_hourly

    tv = TvDatafeed()
    
    if (firstTime): 
        btc_hourly = tv.get_hist(symbol='BTCUSD',exchange='BITSTAMP',interval=Interval.in_1_minute,n_bars=400)
        firstTime = False
        print(btc_hourly)
        
    else:
        new_btc_hourly = tv.get_hist(symbol='BTCUSD',exchange='BITSTAMP',interval=Interval.in_1_minute,n_bars=1)
        
        if new_btc_hourly.index[0] == btc_hourly.index[-1]:
            btc_hourly = btc_hourly.drop(btc_hourly.index[-1])
            btc_hourly = pd.concat([btc_hourly, new_btc_hourly])
        else:
            btc_hourly = pd.concat([btc_hourly, new_btc_hourly])
        print(btc_hourly)
```

The above animate function runs every 2 seconds.The code runs perfectly for the first few times. Printing the required data. However after just 20 or so seconds it gives the following error:

```
if **new_btc_hourly.index[0]** == btc_hourly.index[-1]:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

This is the output I recieve the first few times the code actually works

```
symbol     open     high      low    close  \
datetime                                                                   
2024-03-23 20:47:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64967.0  64980.0  64943.0  64967.0   
2024-03-23 20:48:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64997.0  65009.0  64992.0  65008.0   
2024-03-23 20:49:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  65009.0  65009.0  64793.0  64869.0   
2024-03-23 20:50:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64838.0  64842.0  64778.0  64811.0   
2024-03-23 20:51:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64826.0  64873.0  64794.0  64794.0   
...                              ...      ...      ...      ...      ...   
2024-03-24 03:24:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64957.0  64962.0  64951.0  64952.0   
2024-03-24 03:25:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64955.0  64975.0  64953.0  64975.0   
2024-03-24 03:26:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64984.0  65005.0  64984.0  65002.0   
2024-03-24 03:27:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  65002.0  65002.0  64950.0  64956.0   
2024-03-24 03:28:00  BITSTAMP:BTCUSD  64946.0  64985.0  64946.0  64985.0   

                       volume  
datetime                       
2024-03-23 20:47:00  0.873387  
2024-03-23 20:48:00  0.116192  
2024-03-23 20:49:00  2.181896  
2024-03-23 20:50:00  0.134470  
2024-03-23 20:51:00  1.322647  
...                       ...  
2024-03-24 03:24:00  0.061330  
2024-03-24 03:25:00  0.009868  
2024-03-24 03:26:00  0.094919  
2024-03-24 03:27:00  0.173766  
2024-03-24 03:28:00  0.004474  

[400 rows x 6 columns]
```

I have already checked. The error does not result from any new row being added. It truly does feel random